# How to convert PrefetchDataset to a TF tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

```
def get_train_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=5, 
      label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True,
      **kwargs)
  return dataset

raw_train_data = get_train_dataset(train_file_path, select_columns=CSV_COLUMNS)
```

I created a DataSet from the 'make_csv_dataset' function, which is an PrefectDataset of OrderDict. However, when I fit the model:

```
embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[],
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_data.shuffle(10000),
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_data=val_data,
                    verbose=1)
```

It reports an error:

```
  File "/home/my-env/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py", line 118, in <listcomp>
    inputs = [inputs[key] for key in model._feed_input_names]
KeyError: 'keras_layer_input'
```

I hope to convert this OrderedDictionary into a TF.Tensor, then the 'fit' method should work. How to do that? Or is there other ways to fix that?

In another post, I saw that:

```
The not very elegant workaround you can try is to match the name of input layer with csv column name
```

My csv text column name is 'text'. If I want to use the workaround above, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is somewhere else, but first change the name of the dataset inside the `fit`. You dont have `train_data` variable defined anywhere.

If that still doesn't work then replace your `get_train_data` with this line while poroviding the values to corresponding arguments in it.

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset('PATH OR FILE NAME', batch_size = 1,select_columns = ['Column1','Label'], label_name = 'Label', num_epochs = 1 ,shuffle = True)
```